# Fetch data from local file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to fetch data from local file of csv format and display. How can i get it?
Using this code
`const myData = require('./data.dat')` seems not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not just require a csv file.

When you use webpack as your build tool, you can use the csv loader.
This is the only solution that will work in your browser, as it is opened and interpreted during compiletime and linked statically with your code. 
It will try to parse your csv as json and you use it like a json object.

https://github.com/theplatapi/csv-loader

When you create a node js app, you can load it during runtime with the node file api or use a specific csv library.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback

https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv